# Extracting COVID AdministrativeDivision data from Wolfram Resource

Tags: resourceobject

Wolfram makes the COVID-19 case data available in a form that is conveniently formatted for processing in  Mathematica.

It can be accessed using:

```
data2 = ResourceData[ResourceUpdate["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]]
```

[Syntax provided by swish in his answer to [COVID-19 Wolfram Data Repository Retrieval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216390/covid-19-wolfram-data-repository-retrieval) ]

[image]

Suppose I want to pull out the data for New York state.  Since NY state is in the third row, I can get it using:

```
data2[[3]]
```

However, NY state might not always be in the third row.  So how would I instead extract that row by how it is named in the AdministrativeDivision column ("New York, United States")?

Comment: `data2[Select[#AdministrativeDivision == {"New York", "United States"} &]`?

Comment: ... or `Query[Select[#a == {"New York", "United States"} &]] @data2`?

Comment: Not knowing the full administrative division names, I tend to use `StringMatchQ` on the county names. Not very pretty, and somewhat embarrassing (to me), but it works.

Comment: @kglr Yeah, something along those lines was what I had been trying, and none of my attempts worked. Unfortunately, none of yours do either ;). The first one (after adding the missing bracket at the end) gives an empty output, and the second one gives a `Failure` message. What's needed is the construction provided by LouisB: `data2[Select[#AdministrativeDivision == 
      Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", 
        "UnitedStates"}] &]]`.  I've found Wolfram's Entity syntax to be among the most cumbersome and non-intuitive within the Wolfram Language.

Comment: You could also try something like `data[Select[! MissingQ[#AdministrativeDivision] && 
    ContainsAny[
     CanonicalName@#AdministrativeDivision, {"NewYork"}] &]]`

Comment: @chuy  Thanks, that works!  That's a nice construction, which I will save for other uses as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the code I've been using for various states:

```
res = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"];

cal = Entity[
   "AdministrativeDivision", 
    {"California", "UnitedStates"}];
ny = Entity["AdministrativeDivision",
    {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}];

state = ny;

data = res[Select[#AdministrativeDivision == state &]][[1, -3 ;;]] // 
   Normal;

ts = data[[#]] & /@ {"ConfirmedCases", "RecoveredCases", "Deaths"};

DateListPlot[ts, PlotRange -> {All, All},
 Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> state["Name"],
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

To sum the data over many administrative divisions I've been using this:

```
china = Entity["Country", "China"];
With[{data = 
   res[Select[(#Country == china &&
        Not[Head[#AdministrativeDivision] === Missing]) &]]},
 GraphicsColumn[DateListPlot[data[All, #] // Total,
     PlotRange -> {All, All}, GridLines -> True] & /@ 
   {"ConfirmedCases", "RecoveredCases", "Deaths"}]
 ]
```