# How to access the Wolfram Data Repository

Tags: series-expansion, date-and-time

How I can obtain the raw data of different epidemics in different viruses such as COVID-19, ebola, influenza, etc.?
I consulted the site but I can't figure out how to extract the data in real time to allow me to use Bayes method with Monte Carlo Markov chain using windows to detect the outbreak of the epidemic.

In short how can I obtain the data reported in time series of the different epidemics in the [Wolfram Data Repository](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/)?
For influenza 1918 I find this table [1918 'Spanish Flu' Pandemic In Chicago](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/1918-Spanish-Flu-Pandemic-In-Chicago/), and for COVID-19 I find this table [Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Epidemic-Data-for-Novel-Coronavirus-COVID-19/),
but there is not time series data just general reports for different countries.

Comment: An example of extracting time series data from the COVID-19 dataset is given in this [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218836/22158).  The variable `ts` in that answer is a list of 3 `TimeSeries` objects.